# Line count from grep into count range variable Bash OpenWRT

Tags: bash, grep, openwrt

I am trying to get a range in the format of 0..# to be used in a for loop. I currently have this but it's not grabbing the count properly. I am trying to run this on OpenWRT.

```
count=echo $(( ${grep -c BSS /tmp/ScannedAPs.txt} - 1 ))
```

The Error: `${grep -c BSS /tmp/ScannedAPs.FLT}: bad substitution`

```
range="0..$count"

echo "Count:"
echo "$count"
echo "Time for range"
echo "$range"

for index in $(eval echo "{$range}")
do
echo "${BSS[index]} ${SSID[index]} ${CHAN[index]}" >> /tmp/ScannedAPs_Parsed.txt
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've indicated, the error is in:

```
count=echo $(( ${grep -c BSS /tmp/ScannedAPs.txt} - 1 ))
```

The proper syntax for [Command Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) is `$(command)`.  Say:

```
count=$(( $(grep -c BSS /tmp/ScannedAPs.txt) - 1 ))
```

---

Moreover, you could [avoid using `eval`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) in:

```
for index in $(eval echo "{$range}")
```

by saying:

```
for index in $(seq 0 $count)
```

Alternatively, you could loop (as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20512325/line-count-from-grep-into-count-range-variable-bash-openwrt/20512425?noredirect=1#comment30665712_20512425) by ruakh) by saying:

```
for ((index=0;index<=count;index++)); do
  # Do something here
done
```

Comment: Thanks; +1. Also, I think the arithmetic expansion could be dispensed with, and the `for`-loop written as `for (( index = 0 ; index < count ; ++index ))`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I got it working yesterday but I like your suggestions and will see how they work on openWRT. Thanks again.